# Execute a .sql file with psql and make a log file

Tags: postgresql

I'm dealing with psql for the first time and I need a command that executes a .sql file and after executing, it should make a .log file with the script output. I'm looking for something similar to this other command that I use with SQL Server:

```
sqlcmd -U userid -P password -S serveraddress -i path_to_the_sql_file -o path_where_to_save_log_file
```

Can you help me, please? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would spend some time at the psql [page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

A quick example:

```
psql -U userid -h serveraddress -d some_db -f path_to_the_sql_file -L=path_where_to_save_log_file
```

With Postgres you need to connect to a database with a client. There are other options for inputting commands and capturing output at the link above.